# PHP: how to return the right stuff

Tags: php

In my function I have more variables:

```
        $disallowGallery = 1;
        $disallowFriend = 1;
        $disallowWall = 1;
        $disallowPM = 1;
        $disallowStatusComment = 1;
```

Now, i have a $check parameter. If it contains 'Gallery' the function should return the $disallowGallery variable. If it contains 'Friend' it should return the $disallowFriend variable.

I can do this myself with alot of if else statement / or an switch. But does there exist a more effective/simpler way?

Comment: Just use a if/else switch concstruct. Plain and easy (to read, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return ${'disallow' . $check};
```

Comment: an isset() is probably desirable?

Comment: @jon_darkstar: Error-handling is left to the asker.

Comment: this works nice. If it doesnt find any var with $check, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Johnson It's generally a good idea to increase your warning level so that this causes an error rather than returning nothing...

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest way to store this in my eyes would be an array:

```
$disallow = array(
    "Gallery" => 1,
    "Friend" => 1,
    "Wall" => 1,
    "PM" => 1,
    "Comment" => 1
);
```

Inside a  check function, you would do a check like so:

```
function check("Comment")
....
if (array_key_exists($area, $disallow))
 return $disallow[$area];
else 
 return 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
function isDisallowed($type) {
    $disallowGallery = 1;
    $disallowFriend = 1;
    $disallowWall = 1;
    $disallowPM = 1;
    $disallowStatusComment = 1;

    $type = "disallowed$type";
    return isset($$type) ? $$type : 1;
}
```

But I'd be more tempted to store your configuration in an associative array:

```
function isDisallowed($type) {
    $disallowed = array (
        'Gallery' => 1,
        'Friend'  => 1,
        // ...
        'StatusComment' => 1,
    );

    return array_key_exists($type, $disallowed) ? $disallowed[$type] : 1;
}
```

Comment: Somebody has an unreasoning dislike of variable variables.

Comment: @greg0ire Thanks. I would have been more than happy to debate the merits of variable variables if the down-voter had left a comment...

Comment: @meager: he's either a coward or a mis-clicker